# What is the most efficient way to create empty ListBuffer?

Tags: scala, listbuffer

What is the most efficient way to create empty ListBuffer ?

1. `val l1 = new mutable.ListBuffer[String]`
2. `val l2 = mutable.ListBuffer[String] ()`
3. `val l3 = mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]`

There are any pros and cons in difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Order by efficient:

1. `new mutable.ListBuffer[String]`
2. `mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]`
3. `mutable.ListBuffer[String] ()`

You can see the source code of `ListBuffer` & `GenericCompanion`

Answer (score 9):

`new mutable.ListBuffer[String]` creates only one object (the list buffer itself) so it should be the most efficient way. `mutable.ListBuffer[String] ()` and `mutable.ListBuffer.empty[String]` both create an instanceof `scala.collection.mutable.AddingBuilder` first, which is then asked for a new instance of ListBuffer.

Comment: I searched for some source code.
'object Map' has def empty[A, B]: Map[A, B] = new HashMap[A, B]
buf 'object ListBuffer' doesn't def empty. :(
ListBuffer.empty looks have overhead as you say.
Thank you